# How do reinforcement learning and collaborative learning overlap?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, comparison, collaborative-filtering

How do reinforcement learning and collaborative learning overlap? What are the differences and similarities between these fields?

I feel like the results I get via google do not make the distinction clear.